# Claris ST-2300 shift/brake units compatible with V-brakes?

Tags: shimano, compatibility

I have a Giant hybrid (https://www.giant-bicycles.com/au/cross-city-2) with Shimano Altus (3x8) with Tektro mini V-brakes.

I want to replace the flat bars with drops, which means I have to change the brifters. Claris (ST-2300) looks like it should work for the rear derailleur (8 speed road/MTB is compatible).

The front derailleur is a Tourney TY710. If I want to keep the triple chainring, I believe I will have to change that derailleur? is that correct?

Are v-brakes compatible with ST-2300 shifter (or similar)? This [Shimano document](http://www.bicirace.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/2016-2017_Compatibility_v030_en.pdf) seems to say no, in which case what are my options to get a drop handlebar onto the bike.

Comment: We have several questions about converting flat-bar bikes to drops. The usual advice is "don't bother". By the time you've bought all the parts you need, you'll have spent about as much money as a new bike to end up with a weird frankenbike. You'd almost certainly be better off selling the bike you have and buying the bike you want (possibly second-hand).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the Altus rear derailleur will work with Claris 8 speed shifters. I think the front derailleur will work as well.

Regular V brakes will *not* work with the Claris brake levers. V-brakes require a different leverage ratio at the lever than road caliper and cantilever brakes. The 'mini' V-brakes apparently do with with road brake levers.

The most important thing to be aware of is that replacing flat bars with drop bars is going to significantly affect the bike's cockpit geometry. Frames for drop bars generally have a shorter *reach* (horizontal distance between bottom bracket and top of head tube) than frames for flat bars. This is because the hand position on drop bars is further forward than flat bars. You may end up with bike that has an unridable hand position without a very short stem.

As stated in the comments, flat to drop bar conversions are problematic and not recommended. Apart from the the cockpit geometry issue shifter/brake units are a expensive component (compared to the cost of the whole bike).

If you want the Giant to feel a bit faster, move your bars lower by dropping the stem down to the lowest position on the steerer (i.e., move the spacers from below it to above it), and possibly replace the stem with one a 10mm step longer. Stems are inexpensive and easy to swap out.

Comment: There are Tektro and TRP _mini-_ V brakes for pull ratios of road brakes and Shimano road levers.

Comment: Thankyou all for your detailed comments. I hadn't considered cockpit geometry!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they will work with Tektro Mini Vs in particular. The Mini V design is unique in that it uses what's known as "short pull" brake levers, which all STI levers are. (STIs can be further divided into whether they have the Super SLR cable pull or not, which would be a minor stipulation here if yours did, but Clarises do not.)

Most V-brakes use "long pull" and are not natively compatible with STIs or any but a few specific drop bar levers (Tektro RL520 and Dia-Compe 287V).